# "Syntax error:unexpected end of file " upon bash script execution

Tags: linux, bash

Running Fedora 21 on my VM.
I am receiving "Syntax error:unexpected end of file " upon bash script execution.
[image]

[image]

There is no line 35 in my script. why am I getting the error?

Comment: You missed the last `}` for function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `}` that ends your `test_file` function :

```
test_file() {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Oh... yeah right. feel so dumb now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the function declaration by putting a `}` at the end.